# What is a release manager?

Tags: definition, release-management

What is a release manager?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you a good example:  Where I work, after it is decided that the product is stable and we do an official release (this is a hosted service), the release manager's job is to make sure that the product remains stable (not allowing destabilizing code checkins) and to decide when another official build should be performed and rolled out into the datacenter.  If you want to check code into the code that is under release manager control, you have to go to him and explain what the change does, what its implications are, and why it is important enough to check into the stable code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you google this???

[Release management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Release_management)

> Release Management is the relatively
>   new but rapidly growing discipline
>   within software engineering of
>   managing software releases.

Comment: That article does not meet Wiki's quality standards.